# Facebook comments - view the last 10 posts across a domain

Tags: facebook, api, comments

I have a content rich site that contains many pages, each page has an article that has Facebook comments.

I'd like to provide a widget on my home page that lists the last X comments across the whole site.

I.e. rather than showing the last 10 comments for a specific URL, I'd like to provide the last 10 comments for something like http://www.site.com/content/*.html

Is this possible to do within Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible, you can only get comments for single url.